# How does one access the piped data.frame in dplyr::funs?

Tags: r, dplyr

For example, if the accessor was `..`, this would work:

```
iris %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  # `..` here refers to the object generated thus far. 
  # `.` refers to the column being acted on.
  mutate_all(funs(./sum(..)))
```

Comment: I don't believe you can access the piped one, though you can call `iris` directly.

Comment: @kennyB Please clarify what you are asking for.

Comment: So you want to divide each element in a column by the sum of the column or each element in a column by the sum of all columns ?

Comment: @steveb, by the sum of all the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to take column sums you can

```
iris %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(./sum(.)))
```

If you want to take a total sum, you can just store it as another column

```
iris %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  mutate(totsum = sum(.)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(-totsum), funs(./totsum))
```

I don't think there is much merit to using dplyr for such non column or row grouped operations.

Comment: I think that rather than the sum of the column, they want the sum of the DF. They prolly ought to be using a matrix instead.

Comment: Agreed. Or they can just store the results of `iris %>% select_if(is.numeric) %>% sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

We can use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 as.data.table(iris)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) if(is.numeric(x)) x/sum(x)) else NULL)]
```